# Scroll horizontal a párrafos por columnas css para iphone, ipad y safari

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un contenedor con párrafos que se distribuyen vertical y horizontalmente de a una columna en la pantalla, los párrafos siguen su cause vertical hasta que llegan al tope inferior de la pantalla del teléfono, y automáticamente pasan a una nueva columna hacia la derecha, en *Chrome*, *Firefox* y *Android*, funciona como debe ser, pero en *iPhone* y en *Safari* todos los párrafos se despliegan verticalmente

¿Cómo podría hacer que en *iPhone* y en *Safari* funcione igual que en los demás navegadores y *Android*?

gracias

https://codepen.io/andres3dmd/pen/PagNwz

Comment: Hola Andres Beltrán, me alegra que encontraras la solución. Como referencia para futuras preguntas pidiendo ayuda con la depuración, deberías incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta, en lugar de un enlace a sitio externos. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré que para que funcione en estos motores, se debe poner a dos columnas y usar la propiedad `column-width` con un ancho de pantalla que exceda a nuestro dispositivo, en mi caso *767px*

Por lo que del código planteado en la pregunta, el cambio solo sería en la clase siguiente;

```
.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {}
```

https://codepen.io/andres3dmd/pen/PagNwz